# What is Row ID on Google Sheets and how to find it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I've followed this guide from the Google Support : https://support.google.com/area120-tables/answer/10632692, but I would like to know how can I even get the rowId from a Google Sheets ?

It's required to use the code snippet of the App Scripts.

Thanks!

Comment: Row ID is for a row in Area 120 Tables not Google Sheets.  In your Area 120 Table right click on the row and get the link.

Comment: Oh okay thank you so much. Sadly Area 120 is not available in Europe so can't find my table. So sad!

Comment: Did you create a table from [Area 120 Home](https://tables.area120.google.com/)

Comment: No, sadly at this URL I have this issue : "Tables is not yet available. The Tables beta is currently available in the U.S.". Gonna try to find another way to put my sheets data into a Google Slides!

Comment: So you want to get Google Sheet data into Google Slides?

Comment: Yes exactly. I have a google Sheet with datas. I want that when I click on a checkbox on a specific row, it returns me a URL of my Slides template duplicated, with the specific data from the row display on it. Hope it's clear haha!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to get data from Google Sheets and create a new presentation with the data.

First create a presentation template.

[image]

My Google Sheet looks like this.  The image shows the results. Originally Mary was checked.

[image]

Now the script is bound to Google Sheet.

```
function createSlide() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    values.shift(); // remove header
    let update = false;
    values.forEach( row => {
        // if checked row[4] is true or link is present
        if( row[4] || ( row[5] !== "" ) ) {
          // open the template
          let presentation = SlidesApp.openById("1KjOmacjS_iht2xoBxpnleb28pDMncAu_Ma2NM--PWGY");
          let slides = presentation.getSlides();
          // create a new presentation named for the employee
          presentation = SlidesApp.create(row[0]);
          // copy the template slides to the new presentation
          slides.forEach( (slide,index) => {
              presentation.insertSlide(index,slide);
            }
          );
          // there is only one slide
          slides = presentation.getSlides()[0];
          slides.replaceAllText("{name}",row[0]);
          slides.replaceAllText("{employee no}",row[1]);
          slides.replaceAllText("{work shift}",row[2]);
          slides.replaceAllText("{date of hire}",Utilities.formatDate(row[3],"PST","dd/MM/yyyy"));
          // update the values
          row[4] = false;
          row[5] = presentation.getUrl();
          update = true;
        }
      }
    );
    // update the spreadsheet
    if( update ) {
      values = values.map( row => row.slice(4,6) );
      sheet.getRange(2,5,values.length,2).setValues(values);
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

The new presentation look like this.

[image]

Reference

- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [SlidesApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slides-app)

Comment: Hi again! Thank you so much for your help. Just 2 things that are still on my mind : I have a sheet where I have 50+ rows, and way more in the future. So I just want this script to run for the specific row where I just checked the checkbox (so I don't end up with 50 slides generated at a time :D). And a list point, any way to display the URL of the generated slide on the cell to the right of the checked box? Thank you so much once again, you are saving me a lot of time !

Comment: This example works for any number of rows and number of checked boxs.  I've updated to save the url to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You rock! Just a quick question, why does it gives me a Slide with the page I would like to duplicate but also a white slide after? Tried further things to delete that but didn't find out. Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: You can implement [Slide.remove()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#remove()) for every slide except the first (index = 0);

Comment: Thank you. Very clear. I made another answer to this post to talk about my last issue! I promise!